# Для чего нужны методы before и after в Spring BeanPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring

Смотрел лекции Евгения Борисова "Spring Потрошитель", как я понял к этапу BeanPostProcessor бин уже создан,и выполняется его донастройка, никто технически не запрещает "накрутить" прокси в методе, что выполняется до @PostConstruct (postProcessBeforeInitialization), но прокси принято навязывать в postProcessAfterInitialization, так как PostConstruct должен действовать именно на наш объект, а не на прокси. Но мне все-же непонятно,  зачем нужна вся эта каша с init-методом, почему нельзя просто сделать конструктор, который заменит postProcessBeforeInitialization, зачем между ними нужен init-метод тоже не понимаю, прошу объяснить пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public interface BeanPostProcessor {
Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
    throws BeansException;
Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
    throws BeansException;
}
```

Оба вернут бин, но `before` делает это до **init**-метода, а `after`, как вы понимаете, после **init**-метода. Вызывая BeanPostProcessor для донастройки, учитывайте, что она (донастройка) идет после **init** (`postProcessAfterInitialization`).

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что донастройка идет после init, но технически она может идти и в before? Суть моего вопроса в том, зачем нужен after +constructor +before, почему нельзя ограничиться constructor + after, в каких случаях понадобится и before и init-constructor и after?

Comment: @ggff Вы меня вынуждаете искать информацию в интернете :D Дело в оптимизации программы, ответ есть на англоязычном "стаке". Да, можно использовать только, как вы сказали, constructor+after, но для порядка добавлен и "before". Толковый ответ никто не дает, как и на Буффер и Билдер для строк :)